# Makefile in linux

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to install a benchmark in Linux. Running the `make` command I have some errors. In the MakeFile it is written `This Makefile requires GNU make.` what does it mean? How should I run GNU make?

Comment: Pretty much the only version of make available on Linux is GNU make.  You can be sure by running `make --version` and it should say `GNU make`.  That's almost certainly not your problem: your errors are something else.

Comment: There are a few different versions of the `make` program around. Your makefile is declaring that GNU's `make` program is required. Almost certainly your GNU/Linux distro will have GNU's `make` installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$>sudo apt-get install gmake
```

if you have it already installed
run from the shell

```
$>gmake
```

Comment: I ran gmake but still I have the same error! the software is phoenix.

Comment: Is your problem solved?  If not you shouldn't mark it solved.  I don't know what sanjay is talking about: no Linux distribution I'm aware of, and certainly not a Debian-based one, has a package named `gmake`.  And once the package is installed, the command you run is `make` not `gmake`.

Comment: what is the output of following? ls -l $(which gmake make)

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Jun 25  2008 /usr/bin/gmake -> make
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 162652 May 24  2008 /usr/bin/make

Comment: I guess you have gmake installed.There might be someother issue. Try running make in verbose.Try the following $>make -va